# Grails. Reattach collection of domain objects from HttpSession to Hibernate session

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a collection of domain objects, which I retrieved from a database.
After that I saved this collection in Http session:

```
def cars = Car.findAll() 
session.cars = cars
```

How can I attach these objects again to the hibernate session?
I tried

```
List<Car> cars = session.cars
cars.each {car ->
  car.withSession {session ->
    session.attach(car)
  }
}
```

But I got only: Class
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException
Message
No signature of method: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy53.attach() is applicable

P.S.
I found a workaround:

```
Car.findAllByIdInList(cars*.id)
```

But I don't like it

Answer (score 1):

There's a GORM method that you can use, but it's a method on domain class instances, not the Hibernate Session: [attach](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.4/ref/Domain%20Classes/attach.html). So that should be

```
cars.each { it.attach }
```

or using the spread operator:

```
cars*.attach()
```

However, if you're reloading everything from the database anyway, you should consider storing just the instance ids in the HTTP session instead of polluting it with a bunch of large objects that you discard and rebuild. Wasting server memory like this will have an significant impact on scalability.

Also if this had been a use case for calling a session method, you should only do *one* `withSession` call (and it's static, so call it on the class):

```
Car.withSession { session ->
    cars.each { car -> ... }
}
```

Comment: I tried this too (cars*.attach()), but I got exception: Class
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException
Message
could not initialize proxy - no Session

Comment: Where are you calling that from? There should be an active session in a controller action, or if you call that in a service from a controller action.

Comment: I am calling attach in controller

Comment: That's odd. You can wrap that code in a `withTransaction` block, and even though you're not doing writes and don't need a transaction, it will create a session if there isn't one already and keep it open for the duration of the transaction, so it should help with the lazy initialization issues.